# Saving all the columns from a html table using beautiful soup in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have two kinds of rows I am trying to convert to a table from a website.

The first one looks like this,

```
<tr id="eventRowId_750"> <td class="first left">All Day</td> <td class="flagCur left"><span class="ceFlags France float_lang_base_1" data-img_key="France" title="France"> </span></td> <td class="left textNum sentiment"><span class="bold">Holiday</span></td> <td class="left event" colspan="6">French - Flower Festival</td> </tr>
```

The second kind of row looks like this,

```
<tr class="js-event-item revised" data-event-datetime="2022/02/02 01:00:00" event_attr_id="114" id="eventRowId_444333"> <td class="first left time js-time" title="">01:00</td> <td class="left ImageCur noWrap"><span class="ceImages Australia" data-img_key="Australia" title="Australia"> </span> AUS</td> <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" data-img_key="bull1" title="Low Impact"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td> <td class="left event" title="Click to view more info on Australian Budget"><a href="australian-budget-114" target="_blank">      Australian Budget  (Dec)</a> </td> <td class="bold act blackFont event-444333-actual" id="eventActual_444333" title="">-5M</td> <td class="fore event-444333-forecast" id="eventForecast_444333"> </td> <td class="prev greenFont event-444333-previous" id="eventPrevious_444333"><span title="Revised From -3M">-2M</span></td> <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container" data-event-id="114" data-name="Australian Budget" data-status-enabled="0"> <span class="js-plus-icon alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Create Alert" data-tooltip-alt="Alert is active"></span> </td> </tr>
```

I am trying to convert them into rows using python and beautifulsoup. I use the following code,

```
for items in soup.select("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

But my output looks like this,

```
['All Day', '', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival']
['01:00', 'AUS', '', 'Australian Budget  (Dec)', '-5M', '', '-2M', '']
```

How can I make I get the "low impact" text into the third column where "holiday" is in the first column, and saving the name "France" in the first row into the second column and make it look like this?

```
['All Day', 'France', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival']
['01:00', 'AUS', 'Low Impact', 'Australian Budget  (Dec)', '-5M', '', '-2M', '']
```

This part is not really important but, is it possible to save the span title if it exists in by adding it to the end of the list? the part where it says, "Revised From -3M". So it could look like this,

```
['All Day', '', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival']
['02:45', 'AUS', 'Low Impact', 'Australian Budget  (Dec)', '-5M', '', '-2M', '', "Revised From -3M"]
```

Comment: I don't see `All Day` or `France` in your html.

Comment: sorry @JackFleeting I fixed it, please take a look

Comment: Are you getting the `France` in the output from the `data-img_key`  attribute in the first `<span>` of the first `<tr>`?

Comment: I can’t get it out that’s why I’m asking

Comment: But yeah that would work

Comment: Got it; but now I noticed there's not `<th>` either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely to find a proper pattern, so here we go. I couldn't think of anything to get the title except regex, because it's not tied to a determined tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open("example.html") as html_doc:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for items in soup.select("tr"):
    row = []
    for item in items.select("th,td"):
        text = item.get_text(strip=True)
        if not text:
            title = re.search(r"title=\"(.*?)\"", str(item))
            if title:
                text = title.group(1)
        row.append(text)
    print(row)
```

```
# output
['All Day', 'France', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival']
['01:00', 'AUS', 'Low Impact', 'Australian Budget (Dec)', '-5M', '', '-2M', '']
```

Comment: hey @BcK your method almost does what I want but now its missing the country name at the end in its on string within the list

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest you can get (assuming the pattern hold across all your rows) is something like this:

```
for items in soup.select("tr"):
    row = [item.text.strip()  for item in items.select('td')]+\
          [item['title'] for item in items.select('span[title]')]    
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['All Day', '', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival', 'France']
['01:00', 'AUS', '', 'Australian Budget  (Dec)', '-5M', '', '-2M', '', 'Australia', 'Revised From -3M']
```

Obviously, you will need to manipulate rows to exclude unwanted elements. For example, to remove empty elements, you can change the last line to read:

```
print([element for element in row if element.strip()])
```

which will change the output to:

```
['All Day', 'Holiday', 'French - Flower Festival', 'France']
['01:00', 'AUS', 'Australian Budget  (Dec)', '-5M', '-2M', 'Australia', 'Revised From -3M']
```

Comment: Hi how exactly do you use the element line ?

Comment: You are missing the `'Low Impact'` value. Also according to his expected output, you shouldn't discard the empty strings in the second row.

Comment: @anarchy If I understand your comment correctly, the `print([element for ` etc. line is just a method of eliminating empty elements from a row, if that's necessary.

Comment: @BcK Correct; as I said, this is the closest I can get without hand-tailoring selectors for specific html. The empty element elimination is optional, as OP indicated he might be interested in doing that.

Comment: hey @JackFleeting I can't see the second column that shows the low impact

Comment: @anarchy Yes, that one is missing. As I said, the code in the answer  is as close as I can get you to get both types of rows with one query. Otherwise, different searches need to be tailored for each type of row and then ran separately on the documents containing the respective row types.